# How to get the desired string format in ios

Tags: ios, nsstring

I have the text box with value 2016-01-12.I created the string like this

```
NSString * date = textbox.text;
```

Now the string having values 2016-01-12. I want to display like this.

```
"spent" : "2016-01-12"
```

Now i done

```
NSString * spent1 = @" \"spent\" : ";
NSString * new = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",spent1,date];
```

Now i am getting like this:`"spent":2016-01-12`

But i need `"spent":"2016-01-12"`.thanks for suggestion and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 NSString *str =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\" : \"%@\"", @"spent", textbox.text];
```

Answer (score 1):

For getting date means use this format.

```
NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];
NSLog(@"date is %@",dateString);
```

Comment: yeah i understood but bit confusing i have atextbox with value textbox.text = 2016-01-12 from now what i have to do ..please

Comment: is that user enters or from date picker?

Comment: TextField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];

Answer (score 0):

You can do this --

```
NSString * spent1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" \"spent\" : "/%@"/",date];
```

Or you can use Date formatter which is much more subtle as @Uma Madhavi suggested

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 NSString * date =@"2016-01-12";
    NSString * dateStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"",date];

    NSString * spent1 = @" \"spent\" : ";
    NSString * new = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",spent1,dateStr];
    NSLog(@"------>%@",new);
```